# Open a list rendered popup with API content in vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios, popup

I'm trying to open a popup in a rendered list with custom content from an API request.

For now, I have this code :

```
<template>
  <div class="biblio__all">
      <a v-for="i in items" v-bind:key="i.id" class="biblio__item">
          <div class="biblio__text">
            <h3 class="biblio__title">{{ i.gsx$titre.$t }}</h3>
            <p class="biblio__author">{{ i.gsx$auteur.$t }}</p>
          </div>
      </a>

  </div>

</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
    data () {
        return{
            items: [],
        }
    },
    created(){
            this.axios.get("///API URL")
            .then(response => (this.items = response.data.feed.entry))
        },
    methods: {
        
    }
        
    })
    
</script>
```

I would like to have in the v-for something like another div hidden and when I click on my a link, the popup appears.

I have all my data for the popup on my items array.

Answer (score 0):

you can make separate component for each item and in that component handle its modal state. You can use bootstrap, bulma or pure html,css for making modal. Use `v-show="modalState"` for hiding or showing modal. Define `modalState` in your sub component:

```
data() {
    return {
        modalState: false
    }
}
```

Your final structure:

```
<div class="biblio__all">
      <a v-for="i in items" v-bind:key="i.id" class="biblio__item">
          <!-- component that has code for modal and main item -->
          <subitem :item="i" />
      </a>

  </div>
```